# Html 'month' select from date input no longer showing month string in select after integration of i18n. Ruby on Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n

As it is not easy to explain, here is a picture of the 'select' that is causing trouble: [html month select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Zyid.png)

I can't find any logic into what these letter correspond to so I'm having a hard time finding how to fix this.

The problem occured after the integration of 'i18n' inside my Rails app.

Here is the code for the form which used to work before i18n:

```
<%= f.input :birthdate, as: :date, start_year: Date.today.year - 20,
                          end_year: Date.today.year,
                          order: [:month, :day, :year],
                          label: t(".birthdate") %>
```

Comment: Most likely is that `:month` translation is missing, where is it defined?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I could not find where this comes from but here is a fix I've made for anyone who has the same issue using some jQuery:

```
var month = ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12"];
var count = 0
$("#dog_birthdate_2i > option").each(function(i, item) {
  $(item).text(month[count]);
  count += 1
});
```